# Ajax fired when Filefield "Add Another Item" button is clicked conflicts with my jQuery code

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a node type with a multi-value file field. I am using some jQuery code used by a custom module to modify some of the form elements, but when I click on the *Add another item* button, it completely breaks and wipes out my custom jQuery code.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tips are correct for **Drupal 7**.
Your custom code should be coordinated with Drupal AJAX Framework.
When you click "Add Another Item" this happens:

1. AJAX handler sends all the form with all values, and with point to element which has triggered AJAX.
2. Server returns fully new field. For example, if there were 4 inputs in your field, server will return 5 inputs, not just last fifth.
3. After that new piece of HTML goes through all the behaviors. As you may know, [behavior](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors)'s attach method has two params: `context` and `settings`. `context` is just new HTML for your field.

So, if you add your JS to this schema correctly it must work.

```js
Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.some-class', context).once('YOURMODULE', function() {
      // Do some work here
    });
  }
}
```